# List of Minimum Size with Default Values

Tags: java

This should be a simple one.

I have a string with comma-separated values that I need to split:

```
String[] values = input.split(",");
```

However, I need the `values` to be 5 elements long, no more, no less. So, if `split()` only provides three values, I need the result padded to values with a default provided (null). Output can be a List or an array.

I've hunted and googled and haven't found what I need. I'm hoping that someone will see this and know an existing utility so I don't have to write my own.

Comment: What should happen if there are more than 5 elements? For example when splitting `"a,b,c,d,e,f,g"`. Should it truncate additional elements, or should they be grouped together like in `["a", "b", "c", "d", "e,f,g"]`?

Comment: Some time ago I looked for something like what you indicate and ended up doing something proprietary, a loop going from the amount that it gives you to the desired amount, I have no more solution, I hope someone can give you some integrated method / library

Comment: It should be simple, but you need to provide more logic to how to handle the edge cases. What should happen if, as @FWDekker mentions, we have MORE than five elements as a result of the split operation?

Answer (score 3):

You've confused a programming language with an almanac.

There is no such function; there probably will never be such a function in any major library. It's 2 lines of code to write it yourself:

```
String[] splitInto5(String in) {
    String[] out = in.split("\\s*,\\s*", 5);
    return out.length < 5 ? Arrays.copyOf(out, 5) : out;
}
```

The general idea behind programming languages is that you can program more complex components as needed. This is how you do such a thing - now you have a utility method that splits into precisely 5 elements.

Comment: Nice, very elegant! Note that if you want to truncate elements starting from a possible fifth delimiter, you can remove the `, 5` parameter from `split` altogether. Also, I think writing `","` as a delimiter rather than `"\\s*,\\s*"` behaves the same but is easier on the eye.

Comment: @FWDekker no, it does not behave the same. If the input is `"foo, bar"`, then `.split(",")` will return as second entry `" bar"`, as in, 4 characters: a space, and then bar. This is rarely to never intended when one wants to 'split on commas'.

Comment: As far as the limit on split goes: I have no idea what OP wants. Given A,B,C,D,E,F: Do they want ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E,F"], ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"], or ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]? In the spirit of this answer: Once OP figures it out, they.. program their wishes into computer code.

Comment: My point was that if this was already in Apache Commons, I didn't want to write it myself.